# Change state and readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using **[Bootstrap Switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/)** library and I initialise it inside document.ready as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.initial-chkbx').bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

Users are allowed to upload files I post to the server via `ajax` and if all is well I want to set particular switch to off and make it readonly. The switch id is return to me from the server which is exactly the same has in the markup. Now my issue is, if I do the following

```
 $('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('readonly', true); //it works and makes it readonly as required
```

but if I do

```
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('readonly', true, 'state', false); //this does not seem to work
```

I have also tried to pass in the `BootstrapSwitchOptions` as follows

```
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch({ readonly: true, state: false });
```

without any luck. The above code is in a function called `changeStateAndReadonly` which is called once the files have uploaded successfully.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you try like this? $('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('readyonly', true).bootstrapSwitch('state', false);

Comment: @Himan no that does not work either

Comment: Maybe chaining doesn't work. Can you try like this? 
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('readyonly', true);
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('state', false);

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the options with separate lines.

```
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('readonly', true);
$('#' + checkBoxId).bootstrapSwitch('state', false);
```